# Angular + express + nodemailer not working

Tags: angular, express, nodemailer

The thing is, the combination of these actually works for me when I do it in a separate project, a simple one with no other components, just the app.component.
But when it comes to including it with a website project I'm working on, it just doesn't add up.

Mainly, what has come to my attention is that when I use a parameter in my contacto.component.ts, it compiles but the whole section just kind of crashes and the website stops working as it should, which does not happen on my other project, but i cant just delete it because its what ties together the whole thing. I also wonder if I'm not messing it up with the routes.

Contacto.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

import { MessageService } from '../../services/message.service';

import * as _swal from 'sweetalert';
import { SweetAlert } from 'sweetalert/typings/core';
const swal: SweetAlert = _swal as any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacto',
  templateUrl: './contacto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacto.component.css']
})

export class ContactoComponent{


  constructor(public _MessageService: MessageService) {



  }

  contactForm(form) {
    this._MessageService.sendMessage(form).subscribe(() => {
      swal("Formulario de contacto", "Mensaje enviado correctamente", 'success');
    });

  } 
}
```

this is the message.service used:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  sendMessage(body) {
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/formulario', body); //para nodemailer. http client angular.
  }

}
```

this is the express bit:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const configMensaje = require('./configMensaje');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors())

app.post('/formulario', (req, res) => {
  configMensaje(req.body); //recibe los datos del form
  res.status(200).send();
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Servidor corriendo')
});
```

and this is the nodemailer bit:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


module.exports = (formulario) => {


      console.log('Credentials obtained, sending message...');

      // Create a SMTP transporter object

        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
          port: 465,
          auth: {
              user: 'sofiaespada20@gmail.com',
              pass: 'Valentino10'
          }
      });

      // Message object
      const message = {
        from: `"Sofia" <sofiaespada20@gmail.com>`, 
        to: `"${formulario.nombre}" <${formulario.email}>`, 
        subject: formulario.asunto,
        html: `
        <strong>Nombre:</strong> ${formulario.nombre} <br/>
        <strong>Nombre:</strong> ${formulario.apellido} <br/>
        <strong>E-mail:</strong> ${formulario.email}  <br/>
        <strong>Mensaje:</strong> ${formulario.mensaje}
        `
      };

      transporter.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
          if (err) {
              console.log('Error occurred. ' + err.message);
              return process.exit(1);
          }

          console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
          console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
      });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have a project that have Express+Nodemailer check out this [link](https://github.com/fercarvo/ITSCtecnico/blob/master/routes/impresion.js) It has a POST route that recieves a File and sent it as an email.

Answer (score 0):

Its a very common feature in nodejs. You can find working demo at below link:

https://www.jsonworld.com/demo/detail/17/nodejs/Send-email-using-angularjs-and-nodejs-nodemailer-module